# Can't get Crawling Results

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, class, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class Record:
    def __init__(self, name, year, win, lose):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.win = win
        self.lose = lose
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get("https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/forms/")
    elem = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='form-control')
    elem.send_keys('New')
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    record_list=[]
    team_list=driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='team')
    for team in team_list:
        name=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='name')
        year=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='year')
        win=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='wins')
        lost=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='losses')
        record=Record(name, year, win, lost)
        record_list.append(record)
    print(record_list)
```

I want structured data so I defined *Class*

and made `record` instance before append `record_list`

but i can't get proper result

```
result
```

[<**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F5EBEE0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F629180>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F6291E0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F629240>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F629420>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F629600>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F6297E0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F6299C0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F629BA0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F629D80>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F629F60>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62A140>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62A320>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62A500>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62A6E0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62A8C0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62AAA0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62AC80>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62AE60>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62B040>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62B220>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62B400>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62B5E0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62B7C0>, <**main**.Record object at 0x000001E69F62B9A0>]

Comment: This is my result
[<__main__.Record object at 0x000001E69F5EBEE0>, <__main__.Record object at 0x000001E69F629180>, ... etc ]

Comment: try using .text method. for example name=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='name').text

Comment: record=Record(name.text, year.text, win.text, lost.text) is an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution for the problem.

```
for team in team_list:
    name=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='name').text
    year=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='year').text
    win=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='wins').text
    lost=team.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='losses').text
    record=Record(name, year, win, lost)
    record_list.append(record.__dict__)
```

In the above section, for example for name; you have only search for the element but you are trying to get text content of that element so appending .text will get text value of that element. Also at last you are making class obj and appending it to the result list that's why that weird reference appended on the result list. Simply append dict form of the created object. This should work!